# How do I connect to a MySQL instance without using the password?

Tags: mysql, go, authentication, authorization

I trying to connect db I have set no password for the db I am leaving blank in the password field. But it's not connecting and showing error `connector.go:95: could not use requested auth plugin 'mysql_native_password': this user  requires mysql native password authentication.`. Also I am using phpmyadmin as db so how to connect here is my code

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

var db *sql.DB

func main() {
    // Capture connection properties.
    cfg := mysql.Config{
        User:   "root",
        Passwd: "",
        Net:    "tcp",
        Addr:   "127.0.0.1:3306",
        DBName: "recordings",
    }
    // Get a database handle.
    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", cfg.FormatDSN())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    pingErr := db.Ping()
    if pingErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(pingErr)
    }
    fmt.Println("Connected!")
}
```

Comment: "But it's not connecting." What does that mean exactly? What is the error?

Comment: I have edited the question after your suggestion plz read it again. @Volker

Comment: I'd speculate "phpmyadmin" runs with the permission of the web server which executes its code while this program runs with the permissions of the user whose credentials the OP uses on their system. But we do not have enough information to make this guess educated.

Comment: Also [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/209514) might be a way simpler answer.

Comment: Wile we're on it—regarding that „But it's not connecting” statement—please read [this](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html) carefully.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

That looks a lot like the code from the [Tutorial: Accessing a relational database](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/database-access) which unfortunately does not work. You need to specify `AllowNativePasswords: true` for it to work. That value is `true` by default, but the defaults are only applied if you use `NewConfig()` and not create the `Config` struct yourself. But this will work as well:

```golang
    cfg := mysql.Config{
        User:                 "root",
        Passwd:               "",
        Net:                  "tcp",
        Addr:                 "127.0.0.1:3306",
        DBName:               "recordings",
        AllowNativePasswords: true,
    }
```

Comment: This works, I'd like to understand what it means the "native password" setting though

Comment: In my case, the password is not empty, then I provided its value for the field 'Passwd' and the code works with "connected" output.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change authentication plugin of root user to mysql_native_password in your database. More information about [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/authentication-plugins.html)

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE user = 'root' AND plugin = 'unix_socket';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This code is from Go tutorial. It doesn't work for default code. You have to add one more value in config which is `AllowNativePasswords: true,`

```
cfg := mysql.Config{
    User:                 "root",
    Passwd:               "test",
    Net:                  "tcp",
    Addr:                 "127.0.0.1:3306",
    DBName:               "recordings",
    AllowNativePasswords: true,
}
```

And you're good go go for connected!